# App Center Distribute IOS app using Azure Pipelines: Resource not found

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-app-center

i'm currently working on Azure Pipelines to Distribute the app using App Center.

build and create certificate.p12 and provsion profile working fine, but in App Center Distribute task i got

```
Starting: App Center
==============================================================================
Task         : App Center distribute
Description  : Distribute app builds to testers and users via Visual Studio App Center
Version      : 3.173.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/app-center-distribute
==============================================================================
(node:2022) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2022) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2022) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2022) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2022) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2022) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2022) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2022) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2022) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2022) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2022) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2022) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2022) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2022) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2022) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2022) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2022) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2022) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2022) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2022) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2022) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2022) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:2022) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
##[error]"{\"message\":\"Resource not found: /v0.1/apps/https://appcenter.ms/users/[username]/apps/[appname]/uploads/releases. Correlation ID: bbc...\",\"statusCode\":404,\"code\":\"Not Found\"}"
http response code: 404
Finishing: App Center
```

YAML AppCenterDistribute job

```
- task: AppCenterDistribute@3
  displayName: 'App Center'
  inputs:
     serverEndpoint: Test
     appSlug: 'https://appcenter.ms/users/[username]/apps/TestApp'
     appFile: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/**/*.ipa'
     #symbolsIncludeParentDirectory: false
     releaseNotesInput: 'test 123'
    #isSilent: false
```

and here is my connection configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try to edit the `appSlug` from `https://appcenter.ms/users/[username]/apps/TestApp` to `[username]/TestApp`.

According to the following documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/vsts-deploy

> After you've created the connection between Azure DevOps and App
> Center, Azure DevOps needs to know which app you want to distribute
> the signed build to. You can find the app slug by going to your
> project on App Center, and extracting it based on
> `https://appcenter.ms/users/{username}/apps/{app_identifier}`. For
> example, the app slug for
> `https://appcenter.ms/users/vigimm/apps/SkyTube` is `vigimm/Skytube`.
>
> [image]

Also, the description of argument in [App Center Distribute task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/app-center-distribute?view=azure-devops#arguments) indicates:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure, you're using the latest version of this task. The 404 error I had was due to the underlying API for this task changing.

Mine was still trying to use `/v0.1/apps/{user/org}/{appname}/release_uploads`.

Newer version uses the correct `/v0.1/apps/{user/org}/{appname}/releases`.

According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/vsts-deploy):

> ... ensure that you are using the 3.173.0 version or newer.

[image]